# Any Open Source Web Mapping App importing ASCII grid?

Tags: qgis, mapping, esri-ascii-raster, web

I'm using QGIS were its easy to import my noise mapping data through a raster layer file in ESRI ASCII (ASCII grid) format.

I want to do the same online, without exporting from QGIS, because I want to work dynamically with the output of my prediction software.

What I want is to be able to have the red shape data imported directly and interpreted by the web mapping. Anybody knows any Open Source Web mapping tool able to import this kind (or similar) raster file?

[image: noise grid in red]

Comment: Hi David! Out of curiosity, what noise modelling software are you using?

Comment: I'm working with two different ones, Bellhop and dBSea

Comment: You can use WCS to serve your data as asc grid.

Comment: @nmtoken do you have any example?

Comment: http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/GEMAS/ows?SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&FORMAT=AAIGRID_F32&COVERAGE=Pb_Ap_XRF-grd&BBOX=1537500,937500,6672500,5467500&CRS=EPSG:3035&RESPONSE_CRS=EPSG:3035&WIDTH=10&HEIGHT=10

Comment: @nmtoken thanks a lot! that example you sent to me is quite the same as mine but I was asking about an example of how to process this kind of grid files with WCS. What is WCS? Can I online process my grid files as with a javascript app like leaflet? All the best

Comment: @nmtoken To clarify a little bit, lets say that I have this file [link](http://www.doctorharapos.com/heilig/esriMax2.asc) and I want to show it in an online map as the example of my initial post. Thanks again!

Comment: Way to broad to give full details in a comment, or even in an answer,so some pointers. WCS (OGC Web Coverage Service) is an interface standard for providing access to coverage data (such as ASCII grids).  In the example above the input data is a surfer grid, and the request is for a subset of the original data in ASCII grid.  The above example uses open source MapServer software, you could also use GeoServer, deegree, rasdaman, etc. There's lots of documentation.  Give it a try and come back when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Leaflet and some other javascript libraries to display your files on a webmap
https://ihcantabria.github.io/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field/example_ScalarField.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>ScalarField / ASCIIGrid</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="examples.css" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="title mapTitle">ScalarField</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- CDN -->
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chroma-js/1.3.0/chroma.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin -->
    <script src="dist/leaflet.canvaslayer.field.js"></script>

    <script>
        let map = L.map('map');

        /* Basemap */
        var url = 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
        L.tileLayer(url, {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
            subdomains: 'abcd'
        }).addTo(map);

        /* An ASCIIGrid Raster with Surface current velocity */
        d3.text('data/Bay_Speed.asc', function (asc) {
            let s = L.ScalarField.fromASCIIGrid(asc);
            let layer = L.canvasLayer.scalarField(s).addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());

            layer.on('click', function (e) {
                if (e.value !== null) {
                    let v = e.value.toFixed(3);
                    let html = `<span class="popupText">Surface currents velocity ${v} m/s</span>`;
                    let popup = L.popup().setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent(html).openOn(map);
                }
            });

            layer.on('mousemove', function (e) {
                console.log(e.latlng);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The example looks good but I have some problems:
-My asciiGrid File has dx and dy values instead of cellsize and the coordinate units are utm
I'm converting to utm2deg but the centering is not good because I'm aproximating dx and dy with cellsize.

Do you know if I can use dx/dy fields or how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry but I dont know much about ascii grid files.  What is 'dx'? delta x?

Comment: thanks for your reply! dx is a field of my grid file, you can see an example in the file that nmtoken post above. I think that when the grid file is not a square representation instead of the cellsize field you have two different fields for the x/y coordinates and they have the name dx/dy. All the best